# Azure Data Explorer - solution for storing object properties/configuration

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-explorer

Object configuration and properties are currently stored in an SQL database, and each row is updated to reflect property changes to the object in the master database. The legacy SQL solution also stores event and time-series data, which is being retired and the solution is being moved to Azure Data Explorer. Without the ability to naturally update rows in ADX tables, is there a neat solution to storing this changing object configuration within ADX?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the table has a column that indicates the "version" or the row (this can be either a string column with the version name or simply a datetime column where the last update is the latest time), you can use the [arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) function to get the latest state of the object.

If you want to have a table that always display the latest state, you can create [materialized-view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) that will do it automatically.